# When refreshing a page on localhost, why does the file download hang until I close the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, browser

I'm accessing HTML/JS files on localhost served by Node. When I update the code, Webpack automatically rebuilds the JS files.

Sometimes, after I update some code and refresh the page, the JS file download hangs forever. It still hangs after:

- refreshing
- opening the JS file directly
- opening the HTML in a separate tab
- waiting a long enough time that the file definitely finished rebuilding
- restarting the Node server

It occurs whether or not Devtools is open.

The only ways I've found to stop it from hanging are:

- closing the original tab
- going to the localhost root (http://localhost/)

Why does this happen? I'm using Chrome 88 on Windows 10. I think this is caused by Chrome and not Node, since restarting the Node server didn't do anything.

Comment: Is there a particular asset you can see in the network tab that the hang happens on, or random?

Comment: It's always the main JS file

Comment: are you sure you have "cache disabled" checked in your browser's dev console settings?

Comment: Have you tried this with other browsers like Firefox? Check if you are facing the same issue over there then this is not the issue of browser. You need to try something else then.

Comment: I guess it happens, because your browser exceed limit of maximum parallel open HTTP requests (I mean it's 6? or something..). I faced sometimes similar issue. For me - I had a service worker initialized on the same local domain, which tried to reload himself multiple times and failed, as service worker configuration was old, which at the end freezes the whole tab. What helped - kill service worker, clear whole cache for particular domain, and refresh the page again

Comment: @antpaw "cache disabled" is off. It also occurs with the devtools closed

Comment: @HiteshMishra it doesn't seem to occur in FF, so likely a Chrome issue

Comment: @lorado Interesting idea, but wouldn't that just make it slower, not hang? Regardless, I'm only loading from 2 domains

Comment: @Leo Jiang try updating your chrome browser that might fix the issue.

Comment: @LeoJiang you want "cache disabled" to be on. so you do not hit unfinished bundles twice

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS has a cluster module which may speed up your execution: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html